# Need some help assigning answer to google app maker form

Tags: google-app-maker

on a google app maker form, How do you assign an answer to a question based on another answer or if the question is blank.

for example the time entry form question asks for the date of the entry, if it is blank how do i make the answer todays date?

[image: Picture Question]

Comment: Please see the official documentation here https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/events#onbeforecreate_example or here https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/fields#use_default_values, as well as here https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/appmaker/scripting/api/client#CreateDataSource. Those will describe how to use a model event server side, setting default values in your model setup associated with specific fields, as well as how to assign a 'default' value in client scripting.

Comment: ive seen all this but i need a rough example of how to script this in the client script.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please edit your question and include some code that you have tried to accomplish this. It would also help if you would indicate where you need this, for example do you want this to happen when you click your submit button, or when you open the form would you like a datebox widget prefilled with the date, etc.? Typically this is accomplished by setting `widget.datasource.item.YourDateField = new Date();`, but depending on where you need this it might not work. Please improve your question by editing it.

Comment: i added a picture with more info but i haven't tried anything other than looking around for some obvious solution. How would you apply the script you listed "widget.datasource.item.YourDateField = new Date();" if the value is blank on submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your use case I would suggest the following:

Datebox widget>events>onAttach event enter the following code:

```
var today = new Date();
widget.value = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate());
```

Then enter the following in the onClick event of your 'Submit button', this will repopulate the datebox widget after a new entry was successfully submitted:

```
widget.datasource.createItem(function() {
  var today = new Date();
  widget.datasource.item.Date = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate());
});
```

Comment: alright that worked, what about selecting a category based on the code that was selected in the dropdown? And getting the most recent entry id and adding 1 to the number and updating the current entry id.

Comment: @lucaswilliams If you are using the default Cloud SQL database then your id field in each of your data models should automatically increment by 1 as long as it's a number id field. I guess I'm unsure which dropdown you are referencing in regards to the category. Also, new questions should be asked separately and I suggest following SO guidance here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask so that you get better attention to your question.